# Output current in collector of BC107

Tags: transistors, current, circuit-analysis, bjt, npn

I am working on following circuit involving BC107 NPN Philips TO-92 transistor and voltage source of 4.2 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQP6J8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I got some confusion when measuring collector's current. I was expecting that to be at least 0.2 A but when I insert probes and measure current as shown in the picture I get a reading of 0.0079 A. That would mean an DC Gain (beta/hFE) of Ic/Ib=0.0079/0.0023=~3.37, while this transistor should yield a gain of about 40-200 (I do not have spec for TO-92 though, it's taken from datasheet for BC107 TO-18, can't find any spec for TO-92...).

I would like to understand why am I getting 0.0079 reading when the base current (Ib) is 0.00234 A (confirmed with multimeter).

Ib = (4.2 - 0.7) / 1480 = 0.0023

Ic (expected) = Ib * hFE = 0.0023 * [40:200] = [0.092:0.460] [A]

but real Ic = 0.0079 [A]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87430/discussion-on-question-by-4pie0-output-current-in-collector-of-bc107). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have the transistor connected backwards. Collector is grounded and emitter is used as a collector.

The transistor will work that way, but will have a really low beta, often in the range you are seeing. The Vceo breakdown will also be very low, but okay for your 5V supply. Image from [this](https://components101.com/transistors/bc548-npn-transistor) site.

[image]

Comment: Yes, we've already fond I used wrong datasheet. Actually I can't find a datasheet for this supposedly "BC107/PH10440 PHILIPS (TO-92) PLASTIC NPN" and I think I will just put it on the shelf and get back to learning transistors using one I am more sure about.

Comment: The Chinese often will take part numbers that point to a particular package and cavalierly re-use the part number for a different (more popular) package. I have reels of so-called 1N4004, 1N5819 diodes in surface mount packages, for example. When western companies re-used the part number for the hermetic 2N2222 for example, it was usually called something like PN2222 in TO-92, and the TO-92 2N3904, for example, became MMBT3904 in SOT-23. But that example has not been followed.

Comment: But the USA BJT's ( PN2222A ) will have a different pinout.

Comment: @G36. Yes, there are three common TO-92 pinouts. American (EBC) eg. 2N3904, European (CBE) eg. BC547 and Japanese (ECB) eg. 2SC1815. You can find parts like 8050 in more than one TO-92 pinout, just to keep you on your toes. Fortunately almost all SOT-23 BJT pinouts are the same.